# ORMlite not returning the object I just saved

Tags: android, ormlite

Here is my code that fails ( it is running within an activity and the DB helper creates the WishList object fine in the database )

```
DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance( getActivity() );
int savedID = 0;
WishList wl = new WishList();
wl.setName("abc");
try {
    savedID = helper.getWishListDao().create(wl);
    WishList wl_saved = helper.getWishListDao().queryForId( savedID );
    wl_saved.getId();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is my entity.  The ID field is auto generated.

```
@DatabaseTable
public class WishList {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField( canBeNull = false , unique = true )
    private String name;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<WishItem> items;
    ...
```

What is wrong is the ID that is generated in the Database is not the same one that that ORMlite returns in the call below.  It returns 1.

```
 savedID = helper.getWishListDao().create(wl);
```

The ID in the database is actually 37.  Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?
Using version 4.41

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[ORMLite's](http://ormlite.com/) `Dao.create(...)` method does *not* return the ID of the newly created object but the number of rows in the database that were changed – usually 1.  Here are the javadocs for [`Dao.create(...)`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#create%28T%29).

> Create a new row in the database from an object. If the object being created uses DatabaseField.generatedId() then the data parameter will be modified and set with the corresponding id from the database. ... 
>   **Returns:** The number of rows updated in the database. This should be 1.

When ORMLite creates the object, the generated ID is then set to the `id` field afterwards.  To find the ID of your new object you get it from the object itself:

```
// create returns 1 row changed
helper.getWishListDao().create(wl);
// the id field is set on the w1 object after it was created
savedID = w1.getId();
```

Comment: That was it,  I just went off on the wrong track because the first time I ran my test it passed ( The ID assigned to my object was of course ..... 1 )  While we talking about this,  is it a valid assumption that if the method returns 1 as per the documentation that this can be taken as an indication that the update/insert succeeded ? The documentation does specify this exactly

Comment: Really you can ignore the 1 from `create`.  It's a bit historical.  If there is a SQL issue, `create` will throw an exception.  The number of rows changed is more important when you talk about bulk deleting and updating.

Comment: @Gray Number of rows changed for CREATE still have purpose in SQL. There are SQL statements in which you can select multiple rows from one table and insert them at once into another table. CREATE not always return 1. Hence it is not historical.

Comment: thank you for making it so intuitive, I knew it would have to be something like that but didn't know that someone would actually go the full way to do it :)